# How to specify the order of generator plugins?

Tags: jekyll

I am using 2 plugins. Custom plugin for generating extra content backed by API and `jekyll-redirect-from` plugin to create redirects to the additionally generated content as well.

This is my _config.yml

```
plugins:
- custom-plugin
- jekyll-redirect-from
```

However, the order is not respected and the redirect plugin is executed first therefore the redirects do not work correctly.

I am forced to use the `priority :highest` option in my plugin. This does not seem right as the plugin is for public use.

**Edit**: Seems like it is using a regular Ruby sort that is not stable.